# Does postgres support custom attributes on users/roles?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

Is it possible in Postgres v14 to add custom attributes to a user account and reference those in a RLS policy?

For instance, suppose we have tenants and I wanted to define fred with the custom attribute (tenant_id = 123) and bob with (tenant_id = 987).

Is this possible?  If it is, can these then be referenced in a RLS policy on a table?

Comment: 1) There are not really Postgres users, there are roles. Where a the term user is an alias for a role with login privileges. 2) There are not user/role accounts per se. If you want something like that you will need to roll your own by creating table(s) that store that information.

Comment: usually you define a type with all attributes and afaik it is supported aömost since it exists

Comment: Did you try it using `ALTER ROLE`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, does not work.  Get the error 'unrecognized configuration parameter "company"' and the doc for ALTER ROLE has a finite set of variables but does not say others can be created.  Was curious if there was something other than this, maybe.  Guess not.

Comment: Oh, but placeholder parameter must contain a period, like `my.company`.